# Heroku file uploading error: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "

Tags: flask, heroku, backend, fetch-api

I am building an app which requires user to input an Excel file. After processing it, the app makes a new Excel file available for download. I know Heroku's file system is ephemeral and I don't want the input to be stored forever, i don't care about the input files being deleted, so being ephemeral is not a problem. I am using Flask for backend and HTML, JS, CSS for front.

I am trying to do the standard formData strategy:

1. formData for file input
2. JS fetches '/upload' route with formData as body
3. '/upload' route checks file for errors and then returns error if there is any
4. error pops as alert

It works when I run: "flask run", however Heroku is showing error:

`Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`

HTML for input:

```
<form id="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="flex-container">
          <label for="fileInput" class="upload-label">Select File</label>
          <input type="file" name="file" id="fileInput" accept=".xlsx" required>
          <span class="filename-display" id="filenameDisplay">
               <i class="fas fa-file-excel excel-icon"></i>
               <span id="filenameText">No file</span>
          </span>
          <input id="upload-button" type="button" value="Send" onclick="uploadFile()" disabled="true">
     </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
 function uploadFile() {
                var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('upload-form'));

                fetch('/upload', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                })
                .then(response => response.json())  // Converting response to JSON
                .then(data => {
                    if(data.success == false) {
                        //if not successfull
                        alert('Error in file uploading.\n' + data.error.join("\n"));
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    alert(error.message);
                });

                document.getElementById('upload-button').disabled = true;
            }
```

My "/upload" route in FLASK:

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def upload_file():
    # check if file is in request
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return jsonify(success=False, error="No file selected.")

    file = request.files['file']

    # if no file is selected
    if file.filename == '':
        return jsonify(success=False, error="No file selected")
    
    # if file is valid process it and save it at ~/uploads/name_of_file.xlsx
    if file:
        if not file.filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
            return jsonify(success=False, error="Invalid type")

        unique_name= str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.xlsx' 
        filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], unique_name)
        
        //if folder doesnt exist create it 
        if not os.path.exists(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']):
            os.makedirs(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])

        file.save(filepath)
        erros = read_input.process_file(filepath)  
        
        if erros:
            return jsonify(success=False, error=erros, filepath=filepath) #sends filepath as response

        return jsonify(success=True, filepath=filepath) 

    return jsonify(success=False, error="File upload failed", filepath=filepath)
```

It runs on flask, however the deployed Heroku's version doesn't work.